# Is there a relation between eigenvectors and homogeneous functions, and what is it?

Tags: linear-algebra

when I worked with idea of something being homogeneous. I always felt I reverse engineering what we are doing in linear algebra to find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues. could someone explain it simply

Comment: The word may be a corruption of  *Till Eugenspiegel*  who was a sort of folk hero, earliest published versions about 1500.

Comment: Mina, same spelling in your title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a relationship. Let's recall that a function, say $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, is homogeneous of degree $k$ if it satisfies

$$f(sx) = s^k f(x)$$

for all $x \in \mathbb{R}, s \in \mathbb{R}^{\times}$. This condition says exactly that $f$ is a *simultaneous* eigenvector for the *scaling operators*

$$T_s : f(x) \mapsto f(s x)$$

acting on the vector space of functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $T_s$ has eigenvalue $s^k$.

The scaling operators satisfy $T_{s_1 s_2} = T_{s_1} T_{s_2}$, and you can check that this implies that if $f$ is a simultaneous eigenvector for all of the $T_s$ then the corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_s$ satisfy $\lambda_{s_1 s_2} = \lambda_{s_1} \lambda_{s_2}$. All of this can be understood using the language of [representation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory).

Answer (score 0):

Any homogeneous function $f$ of $n$ variables $x_i$ is an eigenvector of the Euler operator $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\,{\partial }/{\partial x_i}$ with its degree of homogeneity  $k$ as eigenvalue
$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right|_{(x_1, \dots, x_n)}=kf(x_1, \dots, x_n)$$ per  [Euler's therorem](https://planetmath.org/eulerstheoremonhomogeneousfunctions). You can see that $f$ fed into the linear operator comes out again scaled, as eigenvectors do.